# How to create plugin for Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rpc, nuxt.js

This is my `rpc.js` plugin file:

```
const { createBitcoinRpc } = require('@carnesen/bitcoin-rpc')

const protocol = 'http'
const rpcuser = 'root'
const rpcpassword = 'toor'
const host = '127.0.0.1'
const port = '43782'
const rpcHref = `${protocol}://${rpcuser}:${rpcpassword}@${host}:${port}/`
const bitcoinRpc = createBitcoinRpc(rpcHref)

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('bitcoinRpc', (method) =>
    bitcoinRpc(method).then((result) => console.log('That was easy!', result))
  )
}
```

This is my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
...
plugins: [{ src: '@/plugins/gun.js' }, { src: '@/plugins/rpc.js' }],
...
```

If I call `this.$bitcoinRpc('getnewaddress')` somewhere in the component methods, then I get an error, but if I call this method inside the `rpc` plugin itself, then everything works as expected:

```
// plugins/rpc.js:
// Declare constants and inject above
...
bitcoinRpc('getnewaddress').then((result) =>
  console.log('That was easy!', result)
)
```

I get the expected result in the terminal:

`That was easy! 2N8LyZKaZn5womvLKZG2b5wGfXw8URSMptq                                                                                           14:11:21`

Explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Estradiaz https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method outlined by me was correct.

The error that occurred was caused by the fact that on the client side it was not possible to use the server side libraries.